# Unable to read doc file with relative path

Tags: java, servlets, war, relative-path

I have searched for the solution from similar question posted on this forum but could not get out of this problem.

I am developing a website using Java and eclipse. My website reads a doc file and displays on one of the pages. So to read the file I used absolute path: (`C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\Desktop\\wordfile.doc`) during development and it worked correctly.

But during hosting, which is on linux server, I tried to change it to Relative path (`../docs/worfile.doc`) and created a WAR file and hosted. But that is not working. I am confused in using relative path.

The Java file to read the doc file is at: 
`Java Resources\src\com.ssoft.util\readdocfile.java`

Here's my code:

```
package com.ssoft.util;

import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.*;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.*;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.extractor.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;

public class readdocfile {

        /**This is the document that you want to read using Java.
         * @throws Exception **/
    public int totalparas() throws Exception{
        int totparas=0;
        POIFSFileSystem fs = null;
        String[] paragraphs=null;
        String fileName;

        fileName = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\Desktop\\wordfile.doc";


        try {

            fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream(fileName));
            HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fs);

            /** Read the content **/
            WordExtractor we = new WordExtractor(doc);

            /**Get the total number of paragraphs**/
            paragraphs = we.getParagraphText();
            totparas=paragraphs.length;
            we.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return totparas;
    }   


    public String[] readDocument() throws Exception{
        POIFSFileSystem fs = null;
        String[] paragraphs=null;

        String fileName = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\Desktop\\wordfile.doc";
        try {
            fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream(fileName));
            HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fs);

            /** Read the content **/
            WordExtractor we = new WordExtractor(doc);

            /**Get the total number of paragraphs**/
            paragraphs = we.getParagraphText();
            we.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return paragraphs;
    }   

}
```

And the jsp file from where reading of doc file triggers is in `WebContent`

Comment: Can somebody help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Files with Relative path in java are resolved relatively to the directory from which java is started.

So if you are running a server like tomcat the relative path is probably relative to the .sh/.bat that you used to start the server.

Comment: Hi Sebastien, the WAR file is deployed at "/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/www.ssoft.com/". Now what would be the relative path to be used. One more point i have forgotten to mention is, after deployment the path of the class files is "/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/www.ssoft.com/ssoft/WEB-INF/classes/com/ssoft/util. With respect to this what would be the relative path I should use.

Comment: Hi Sebastien, can you please tell the solution

Comment: Could you please clarify the absolute path to your doc file in the ptoduction environment.

Comment: the absolute path of the word file probably is "/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/www.ssoft.com/docs/wordfile.doc".

Comment: Hi Sebastien, I still could not resolve this problem. Can you please suggest how to resolve this

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to find the error in your relative path is to compare both absolute paths. Add those in and if there are still issues we can help better.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.